# How to set the redirect URL to a specific domain when successfully logged in with ADFS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs

I'm authenticating users trough ADFS using OWIN in ASP.NET MVC.

I use the same ADFS server for two diferent sites.
The first site is **www.mysite.com** and the ADFS authentication works propertly.

The second site is www.mysite**admin**.com (the administrative site), but when the user succesfully logs-in in the ADFS site, the redirection is made to www.mysite.com and not to the "admin" site.

Does someone knows why is this happening. I asked to the ADFS Service owners and they said that both sites are registered as relying party trust.

I want to specify the respective redirection URL on each site, but I haven't found anything helpful over the internet.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both sites are set up with RP trusts and both have the correct redirect URI this will work.

These are separate applications?

It sounds like both sites have the same URI?

Comment: Both sites are separate applications and both have different URI configured in the ida:Wtrealm key in the web.config

Comment: Sorry, I meant both RP on the ADFS side. Do they have different redirect URI?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. That was exactly the problem here. The ADFS administrators only had one of the URI registered as relying party trust with two different response urls, so the ADFS was always responding to the same principal response URL. They are going to register a second RPT and set a propper response URL. I appreciate a lot your help.